# How to properly stub a function return value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testdoublejs

- **Premise:** JS ES6, NodeJS
- **Testing Framework:** [TAP](http://www.node-tap.org/)
- **Mocking Library:** [testdouble.js](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js)

---

I am attempting to mock the return value for the method of my class and keep receiving this error:

> not ok Unsatisfied verification on test double.    Wanted:     - called with `(true)`.    But there were no invocations of the test double.

Here is my testing code:

```
// Imports for unit testing
const tap = require('tap');
const Subject = require('../src/iTunesClient.js');
const td = require('testdouble');

let reqJson;

// Ensure the iTunes class methods are called
tap.test('iTunesClient class methods function as intended', (t) => {
  t.beforeEach((ready) => {
    reqJson = td.replace('../src/reqJson.js');
    ready();
  });

  t.afterEach((ready) => {
    td.reset();
    ready();
  });

  t.test('iTunesClient.getData', (assert) => {
    const callback = td.function();
    const subject = new Subject();
    subject.setTerm('abc 123');
    subject.setURL();

    td.when(reqJson.get(td.callback)).thenCallback(true);

    subject.getData(callback);

    td.verify(callback(true));
    assert.end();
  });

  t.end();
});
```

Specifically, this line is related to my issue:

```
td.verify(callback(true));
```

How can I fake the callback value of `true` for `reqJson.get()`? Right now, `Subject.geData()` is a method of the `iTunesClient` class which calls another file, `reqJson.js`, to use its exported `get()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to update this question, as I recently solved this issue. Essentially, I had two issues:

1. Account for both reqJson function parameters
2. Account for all callback return values

Per [testdouble documentation](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/blob/master/docs/5-stubbing-results.md#tdmatchersanything) for item 1:

> When passed td.matchers.anything(), any invocation of that test double function will ignore that parameter when determining whether an invocation satisfies the stubbing.

Hence, I adjusted my line of code as follows:

**Before:** `td.when(reqJson.get(td.callback)).thenCallback(true);`

**After:** `td.when(reqJson.get(td.matchers.anything(), td.callback)).thenCallback(null, null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell from your example, but it looks like you're requiring `iTunesClient` before you call `td.replace`. In this case, the real `reqJson` module will be required and cached on line 3.

You need to call `td.replace` early enough to avoid this, e.g. in between requiring `tap` and `iTunesClient`.